# purchase YouTube api quota

Tags: youtube-api, quota, youtube-data-api

I have a pretty commercial we application and I want to use YouTube as my back-end to store videos which are being uploaded by users.

We want to even pay YouTube (Google) to provide extra quota for our users to upload videos through its API.

Is there any alternative to YouTube's api?

My first and maybe stupid solution was to have several YouTube Developer accounts and have a load-balancer server to amortize uploads within different Google Developer account and never run out of quota. But it is a technical solution not ethical and maybe would be in conflict with the YouTube API's term of services.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: @JAL: Only programmers with enough experience can answer this question. Solution to this can have a hierarchical solution. Maybe using another API would be my answer.

Comment: Questions asking for API recommendations are off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: @JAL: so tell me where should I ask this? How can I find a group of creative developers who are eagerly waiting for questions?

Comment: @MaziarAboualizadehBehbahani Have you solved your problem? Were you able to buy more youtube api quota? The reason I am asking is because I want to do the same. I dont want to start a business relying on a "free" api service

Comment: @Keeto no, no answer yet. The closest solution would Vimeo https://developer.vimeo.com/

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is just to store, you should use Google Drive Storage instead of YouTube.

Either way, YT API won't let other people to upload videos into your account.

Comment: I think my question is not clear. I have some website like facebook. when people want to upload their videos to my website (or attach that to the post) and in the back of the scene I wanna use you-tube API to pushthem to you tube.